# Run a javascript file on VPS with node.js?

Tags: node.js, centos, vps

I have followed this guide to install Node.js on my centOS VPS.
[This one](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-run-a-node-js-app-on-centos-6-4-64bit)

And i have a simple chat.js file on the server looking like this:

```
var http = require('http');

var s = http.createServer(function(req, res){
res.writeHead(200, {'content-type':'text/plain'});
res.end("hello\n");
console.log('user entered');
});

s.listen(8000);
```

And here is the question.
How do i run that chat.js file?
I have tryed to navigate to the folder and "node chat.js"
but then it gives me an error:

```
 -bash: node: command not found"
```

can any tell me what im doing wrong?

Comment: You might not have node installed. Try "which node". It should give you the path to node if it's installed on your VPS.

Comment: which node                                               
/usr/bin/which: no node in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbi
 which node                                               
/usr/bin/which: no node in (/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbi
n:/usr/bin:/root/bin)

Guss it means its not installed ?

Comment: ty.. i reinstall'd node.. run the which node and got a path. and now i can run files by: cd/TO/THE/PATH/ node file.js

thanks for youre answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js is either not installed, or it cannot find the installation. The command `$ which node` will verify this. If this is the case, you'll need to add the installation dir of node.js to your `$PATH`.

Comment: you where right. it was not installd :). made a reinstall and everthing works now.